# как добавить в Recyclerview такую галлерею?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приложений для вывода персональных данных пользователя использую Recyclerview , в конце списка нужно выводить фотки как на рисунке,подскажите в какую сторону копать

Comment: Используйте `ViewPager`

Comment: Или горизонтальный RecyclerView в нужной ячейке вертикального RecyclerView.

Comment: У адаптера можно переопределять ID вьюх и тем самым у них будут разные ViewHolder-ы. Таким образом можно "нарулить" нужное поведение.